# Filtering output of tcpdump and running script when string is found in realtime

Tags: linux, awk, raspberry-pi, tcpdump

I've got this command which displays packets received and sent on port 1700.

tcpdump -AUq port 1700

In the packet there is the string `rxpk`, but most of the packets don't have it. When the output contains this string I want some script (which flashes a led) to run.

```
tcpdump -AUq port 1700 | awk '/rxpk/ { print | "/path/to/blink_led 18" }'
```

But it appears that it only matches the first time an `rxpk` is found, subsequent occurences wont trigger the `{ ... }`-part

Anybody an idea why? Or even an other approach to run a script when `rxpk` is received?

Comment: Does blink_led do something every time it reads a line of input, or does it do something once regardless of input?

Comment: The blink_led has to be called everytime the string `rxpk` is printed by tcpdump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the LED blinks only once is that when you print to a pipe, the pipe remains open, so there is only one invocation of `blink_led`. If `blink_led` was to read its stdin for instructions then this wouldn't be a problem. If it fails to read stdin and exits, then `awk` will exit too.

The conventional way around this is to `close()` the pipe so the next invocation starts a fresh one:

```
tcpdump -Alq port 1700 | awk '
  BEGIN { mypipe="/path/to/blink_led 18"; }
  /rxpk/ { print | mypipe; close(mypipe); }'
```

`system()` is fine too, as suggested by @heemayl (and probably better if `blink_led` has no interest in reading stdin at all).

You'll notice I'm using `-l` instead of `-U`, `-l` flushes stdout to avoid pauses if the output you want is waiting in a stdio buffer (`-U` enables whole packet flushing when you use `-w` to write to a file).

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to match multiple packets and give the match to the script as an argument? eg `/(rxpk|txpk|stat)/` don't know if the regexp is that versatile?

Comment: You can use an ERE of `/(rxpk|txpk|stat)/` as the awk pattern, but it won't tell you what it matched, you'll need to call `match($0,/(rxpk|txpk|stat)/); print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)` from the `{ }` block ,or *instead*  of `/../` use `match(..)` (though both will only show the first match, in case that's important).

Comment: There is also a command called ngrep (netgrep) which might be more suitable for the packet collection